# Как у всех элементов списка удалить определенный набор символов и заменить другим?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список, к примеру :

```
list = ['Слово\nВтороеСлово\n5.00 €\n0', 'ТретьеСлово\n7.00 €\n0', 'ЕщеСлово\n3.0 €\n0']
```

Нужно везде удалить '\n' и '\n0' и заменить на пробел

Что должно получиться:

```
list = ['Слово ВтороеСлово 5.00 €', 'ТретьеСлово 7.00 €', 'ЕщеСлово 3.0 €']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q = [re.sub(r'\n', ' ', i) for i in list]
newtest = [x[:-1] for x in q] 
print(newtest)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так:

```
a = ['Слово\nВтороеСлово\n5.00 €\n0', 'ТретьеСлово\n7.00 €\n0', 'ЕщеСлово\n3.0 €\n0']
listt = []
for i in a:
    listt.append(i.replace("\n0", " ").replace("\n", " "))
print(listt)
```

Comment: `a = [i.replace("\n0", " ").replace("\n"," ") for i in a]` если в одну строчку

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для каждого элемента списка функцию `replace`

`.replace('\n', ' ')` и `.replace('\n0', ' ')` соответственно.

Только надо будет переназначить значение элемента списка, а не просто применить к нему функцию, потому что `replace` возвращает копию строки, а не напрямую изменяет значение

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [i.replace("\n","") for i in list]
```

Comment: Вместо "\n0" получится 0, а надо пробел.

Comment: @Эникейщик хотел бы поинтересоваться, а это нормальная практика указывать в имени переменной str, list, dict, set и т.д.?

Comment: @Shush1k Нет, так лучше не делать.